# Check a string if it contains a string that's inside a list python

Tags: python, string

```
String = "Alienshave just discovered a way to open cans"
Arr=["Aliens","bird","cactus","John Cena"]

if any(words in String for words in arr):
       print String
```

This script displays `Alienshave just discovered a way to open cans`

but i dont want it to `print` `String` since the word `Alienshave` in `String` is not exactly the same as the word `Aliens` found in `Arr`

How do i do this so that the basis for comparison are the strings inside an array and doesnt act like a wildcard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using regular expression with word boundary(`\b`):

> Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word.
>   A word is defined as a sequence of Unicode alphanumeric or underscore
>   characters, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a
>   non-alphanumeric, non-underscore Unicode character. Note that
>   formally, `\b` is defined as the boundary between a `\w` and a `\W`
>   character (or vice versa), or between \w and the beginning/end of the
>   string. This means that `r'\bfoo\b'` matches `'foo'`, `'foo.'`, `'(foo)'`,
>   `'bar foo baz'` but not `'foobar'` or `'foo3'`.

---

```
string = "Alienshave just discovered a way to open cans"
arr = ["Aliens","bird","cactus","John Cena"]

import re
pattern = r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(arr)) # => \b(Aliens|bird|cactus|John Cena)\b
if re.search(pattern, string):
    print(string)
# For the given `string`, above `re.search(..)` returns `None` -> no print
```

Comment: thanks for this, and for the explanation.  :thumbs up:

Answer (score 0):

I used `String.split()` which splits the string into words.